# How to calculate the required force to from lever to pushrod in order to close calliper in a hydraulic braking system?

Tags: forces

How to calculate the required force to from lever to pushrod in order to close calliper in a hydraulic braking system?

Through test and data i have determined the average force on a bicycle lever is around 60N for the bike to stop quickly. However I'm trying to calculate the force/area to find the pressure for the cylinder - to push the hydraulic fluid into the calliper. Any help is much appreciated!

Ben

Comment: I have some Shimano master pistons at home—I can measure one for you shortly.

Comment: https://forum.bikeradar.com/discussion/12601124/mechanical-advantage-of-hydraulic-brakes-piston-diameters has some incomplete bore diameters.

Comment: are you asking about literally how much force is required to close the caliper, ie frictional, compressive, and spring resistance losses that factor in along the way to moving the pistons enough to close the pad gap?

Comment: I'm getting around 9.8mm for the lever piston, with some margin of error because my calipers are utter garbage.